# ImportError: No module named engine - Django suit related?

Tags: python, django, importerror, django-suit

I am using Django and Django Suit V2 -

I am trying to create a custom home page for my django site using templates.

I keep getting this error: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suit/apps.py", line 89, in add_suit_default_template_tags from django.template.engine import Engine 
ImportError: No module named Engine

I want to make sure of what I'm doing before I go in and mess with the main files.

Anyone else deal with "No module named Engine" error before? Any Suggestions?

UPDATE -  ok I corrected the first issue - I made sure the python interpreter was pointing to the virtualenv (it was already activated, so I deactivated and then reactivated). Was able to do a collectstatic with no error. I have now generated a different error which I will post in a different question since it's not directly related here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have an old version of Django installed. The import

```
from django.template.engine import Engine
```

should work in Django 1.8+.

Comment: I am using Django 1.9

Comment: The error suggests that Django 1.9 isn't installed. Perhaps you need to activate the virtualenv where you have installed Django 1.9.

Comment: I had to reactivate my virtualenv - thanks. Part of the issue was the python interpreter apparently. THANKS!